# Lighting a table is just not working

Tags: video, lighting

We are trying to take short videos of a small product.
The video happens on a table of 1x1 Meters, where the camera is about 40cm above the table-static.

1. I have 4 6000k led bulbs each 20W (=100W) , 1 meter from each corner
2. I have a little light comes out of the window

What happens is that **only when I film very close to the object ( 10-20cm above) I get great video. If I go up to 40cm and more - you do not see details good enough.**

1. Have tried good **Cannon**, and **Fugi** with different lenses
2. Tried **iPhone 6** that surprised me with much better videos.

But still, 40cm above that table you see good picture but not detailed enough.
**On 3 of the camera I used, I get great picture only when close to the product.**

What else can I do on a budget ? if I put diffuser around the table would it help ?

Comment: Maybe you should add screenshots of your video to better show what you think is amiss. If you move farther away, your video will naturally show less details. Do you mean there are underexposed parts? Or does the light blow out all of your product's contoure?

Answer (score 1):

That sort of "product shot" is frequently done by firing your lights through a diffusing "tent" that surrounds the subject.  You're looking to get good "modeling" of the shape and detail without specular reflection.

Cars are frequently lit the same way, but with a bigger tent.

Here's an example, although you can rig your own cheaper: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1123911-REG/surface_light_ltd_68056998365_pop_up_photo_studio.html

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want to diffuse the light. Sounds like you have enough, and well-distributed.

It's not clear what you need from the video, though. If you need a lot of detail, fairly close-up, consider a telephoto macro lens.